mat-checkbox produces overflow
I have a strange behavior. I have this template:
<div style=overflow-y:auto>
    <mat-checkbox>Some checkbox</mat-checkbox>
</div>

It produces a vertical scrollbar. Why?
The scrollbar vanishes if I define the height of the checkbox to be four pixels larger than it actually is (according to chrome devtools).
<div style=overflow-y:auto>
    <mat-checkbox style="height:44px">Some checkbox</mat-checkbox>
</div>


It's because the "ripple" height (the little animation when click)

Thank you. How would you fix it without losing the ripple? I tried disableRipple, but that didn't help.

why not use, e.g. margin-bottom:-6px?.

I tried, but that didn't work. Anyway, it would, in my estimation, similar to what I'm currently using height: 44px. That works, but makes assumptions about checkboxes that may break with some future material update. What I really would like is to understand where the behavior comes from and why a 40x high element (according to DevTools) creates an overflow to a DIV that has no defined height.
